# ggplot2 R charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm new to R and started with basic plots. I have used a simple excel table which has the following columns- Family, Family Name, Product.ID, Sales, Time, Value

The table is similar to the below snapshot

[image: Sample Data]

I used the code below but for some reason the when I try to group the chart by Family Name it is just showing a single color and even the legends is not appearing for all values in Family Name

```
library("ggplot2")
library("data.table")
library("readxl")
Data<-read.xlsx("C:/Users/vc/Desktop/Sales Data.xlsx")
setDT(Data)
Plot<-ggplot(data = Data,
             aes(x=Time,y=Value,group='Family Name',shape='Family Name',color='Family Name')) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

I have attached the output graph and it doesn't make any sense.

[image: Output Plot]

Comment: Use `` (stating you are describing the variable) and not '' (then you create a string).  Also your variable seems to have the name Family.Name not Family Name as in your code. Try ```aes(col = Family.Name)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

- For depiction of date on x axis you need to convert variable to `as.Date()` first

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            Family = c("19A", "19A", "19A", "19A", "19B", "19B", "19B", "19B"),
       Family.Name = c("A Box","A Box","A Box",
                       "A Box","B Box","B Box","B Box","B Box"),
        Product.ID = c("AA980","AA980","AA980",
                       "AA980","AL345","AL345","AL345","AL345"),
             Sales = c("actualsalesunit",
                       "actualsalesunit","actualsalesunit","actualsalesunit",
                       "actualsalesunit","actualsalesunit","actualsalesunit",
                       "actualsalesunit"),
             Times = c("01-01-2021","01-02-2021",
                       "01-03-2021","01-04-2021","01-01-2021","01-02-2021",
                       "01-03-2021","01-04-2021"),
             value = c(63L, 34L, 93L, 99L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)

df %>%
  mutate(Times = as.Date(Times, '%d-%m-%Y')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Times, y = value, color = Family.Name, label = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(size = 3.2, position =position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>